# dynamically setting textview background color

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

I have a table 'D' that each row has 4 textviews in it. I have set onlicklistener and it works. What I want is for the user to press on any text view of that row and the text background changes to ltgray. I will solve whether each textview or the whole row gets set.
Right now only the last textview gets set to ltgray no matter what tv the user presses. Based on the code my assumption is that I can set each tv to an onclick value by the index of x in the code: But that aint working. Cant I access each textViewB by the x?. The code shows the tvB getting set for other situations but this new one of setting the text background of all textviews. I dont want row background. That is easy and works. but only the borders show. My need is the text background to changes for all 4 tvs in that table row.
Thanks you in advance:

```
try {
        for(int x=0 ; x<loopCount; x++){
            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(headerCellsWidth[x + 1], LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.setMargins(2, 2, 0, 0);

            Log.d("Loadrunner", "info[x] " + x + "  " + info[x]);
            final TextView textViewB = this.bodyTextView(info[x]);
            textViewB.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            tableRowForTableD.addView(textViewB, params);
            //*************************************** Clickable cell
            tableRowForTableD.setClickable(true);
            tableRowForTableD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //tableRowForTableD.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
                    textViewB.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item on aisle select/deselect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            tableRowForTableD.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    //tableRowForTableD.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item on aisle Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
                }
            });
            //***************************************************************
        }
    }   catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Its all done in code. There are no xml or styles.

Comment: Problem is: You are setting the OnClickListener in each loop. A view can only have one OnClickListener, so only the last one will work. Hint for a solution: Keep an array of textviews for each tableRow so you can loop over this array on click of the row

Comment: @devnull, you nailed the problem here. Only the last textview gets the background change. I really dont want to have to track and synchronize an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.your_color));
```

or

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

or

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

I believe what you want is in the **onClickListener**. You have already the view, just change that view clicked. For example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) v.getParent(); 
    for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < row.getChildCount(); itemPos++) { 
        View view = row.getChildAt(itemPos); 
        if (view instanceof TextView) { 
            textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
      }
    } 
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item on aisle select/deselect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: But the clicked view is the table row ... OP wants to change the background color of (all) textviews in that row

Comment: In the **OnClick** add:

ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < row.getChildCount(); itemPos++) {
    View view = row.getChildAt(itemPos);
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
         textView = (TextView) view; 
         textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }
}

Comment: You should add that to your answer

Comment: I will in the future have added a column in the db that will track the record as it is selected. Then as I read the record each tv will set bg accordingly. That will take of its self. Right now I am stuck on a UI event issue.

Comment: @Amg91, I am interested in this line of code. Tho I am not, at this time in a position to add what I see as another layer above my current design. I added your code and imported the VG. I get an undefined var of textView. Thank you for your answer. I added TextView declaration before it is the erro subsided. But the textView shows up as never used. You line of code has led me into a greater understanding of referencing the object. But in its current state has not made a difference in the UI.

Comment: As I add these changes the UI changes in very interesting and delightful ways! I get real user feedback from the app! Sure beats looking through trace dumps! LOL.

Comment: The code that amg91 supplied will not locate the tv child clicked because the onclick is the view row. But it lends itself for further analysis.

Comment: But in accordance with good coding techniques one does not want to assign large reiterative coding loops to each textview. This creates a large application with excessive logic. There has got to be a better alternative. And I will find it or somebody might chime up. Either way it very all good!

Comment: @Amg91, Your code was the answer with one except. The v.getparent was looking up a level. I changed that to TableD.getChildAt(itemPos); Now I next to drill into the textitem. Somebody knocked it down. I clicked back up.

Comment: And this is so slick. Now am referencing other tables from an onclick in one of other the tables!

Comment: My apologies. And nice one. Thank God we all are a huge team to solve fellows' problems. Best regards.